# Why we don't have to define the type of an argument when creating an object from a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, dynamic-typing

I am new to Python and I have just created a class as part of the online course I am taking.

```
from math import sqrt

class Line:

def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
    self.coor1=coor1  #tuple (x1,y1)
    self.coor2=coor2  #tuple (x2,y2)

def distance(self):
    return sqrt((self.coor2[0]-self.coor1[0])**2+(self.coor2[1]-self.coor1[1])**2)

def slope(self):
    return (self.coor2[1]-self.coor1[1])/(self.coor2[0]-self.coor1[0])
```

This is a class for `Line` and helps me find the distance between two coordinates. I am wondering, since a coordinate needs to be a tuple, how does Python know this? Why don't I need to define this in the `def __init__`?

Comment: Another angle: Why would python need to know that your arguments have to be tuples?

Comment: Python doesn't care if you use tuple or something different - ie. strings or integers. You can use `if isinstance(coor1, tuple):` to use only tuples but you still can put tuple with 3 or more numbers or with strings - `Line( ("Hello", "World"), ("Anonther", "tuple", "with", "strings") )` and you would have to use more `if` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not python who knows that's a tuple! you should handle it if you want python to presume that `coor1` and `coor2` are tuples. now if you create an object of your class like :

```
line1 = Line("hi","Sorath")
```

`coor1` would be equal to `hi` and `coor2` would be equal to `Sorath` and both of them are strings.

`coor1` and `coor2` can be everything, you should define the type of them while you are passing values or when you are writing `__init__` !

```
def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
    if type(coor1)==tuple:
        self.coor1=coor1  #tuple (x1,y1)
    else:
        self.coor1 = () #empty tuple

    if type(coor2)==tuple:
        self.coor2=coor2  #tuple (x2,y2)
    else:
        self.coor2 = () #empty tuple
```

Comment: So how would I define the types in __init__?

Comment: @Sorath you wouldnt bother in Python its up to you to keep track of your types Python literally doesnt care

Comment: @Sorath, see my answer for an example of how to declare the variable types. Just ensure you're on Python 3.6

Comment: @Sorath use `type(coor1)==tuple`, check out my answer again

Answer (score 0):

**__init__()** is just the constructor of the class. This method is called when you create a new object.

`def __init__(self, coor1, coor2):` means that you want the two arguments (i.e. coor1 and coor2) to create the object. For example, when you create an object, you can do:

```
coor1 = (2, 6) # a tuple
coor2 = (-4, 12) # a tuple

l = Line(coor1, coor2) # create an object Line
```

> Python is interpreted language and dynamically typed. So the types of variables are inferred by the interpreter.

To know the type of a variable, you can use the function `type(object)`. For instance

```
type(coor1)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should give a good explanation on why:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language

TLDR: the onus is on the developer to ensure the data type you're using is right for that function. Since Python is dynamically-typed, it would "know" what the data type would be upon value assignment.

Python 3.5+ though introduced the declaration of the variables' data type (i.e., type hinting):

```py
def __init__(self, coord1: tuple, coord2: tuple):
    # initialize
```

Comment: well this is not going to force `corrd1` to be `tuple` !